Minimum distance between electrical water supply piping in a basment
Is there a minimum distance between the electrical and supply water pipes in a basement? I have a few electrical wires crossing over water supplies to the kitchen. I will be replacing some of the pipes because of corrosion. Most of which would obviously be above and not in a wall in the basment.

I do not think there is a minimum.  You do not want them touching to prevent rubbing, but there are pictures on here of stuff in code, but what I would try to move/not install as is.  Common sense says not close.

No, but the incoming water supply is required to bonded to the electrical grounding system within 5 feet of the entrance to the building if it is metallic. If there is a water meter on the incoming supply that is required to be jumpered with a suitably sized bonding jumper.
Consequently, if you have metallic water supply lines near electrical supply wires in the house the water lines will be grounded back through the bonding to the electrical ground.

The incoming pipe has to be metallic for this to apply. Most modern waterlines are not.

I said that in my post "if it is metallic". The bonding at the water meter also only applies to metallic piping systems.

0 inches. 0 centimeters.
Code makes no mention of it.
This implies that the presence of water pipes and electricity cables or conduits in close proximity has not killed enough people to show up in code, so it's not terribly hazardous in practice. Places where water and electricity have killed enough people all need GFCI protection, but that is for water not in pipes.

Still good to not let them touch for mechanical reasons.
